# MultiValueMap get values

Tags: java, spring, apache, hashmap

hi im trying to access a MultiValueMap which is in a Hashmap

this is my HashMap inside`projectDetails` HashMap

```
private HashMap<String, ClassDetails> classDetailsMap = new HashMap<String, ClassDetails>();
```

inside that `classDetailsMap` i have `MultiValueMap` called `methodDetailsMap`

```
private MultiMap<String, MethodDetails> methodDetailsMap = new MultiValueMap<String, MethodDetails>();
```

when im trying to access the `methodDetailsMap` by

```
        Set<String> methodNamesSet = projectDetails.getClassDetailsMap().get(cls).getMethodDetailsMap().keySet();
    String[] methodNames = methodNamesSet.toArray(new String[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
        String methodName = methodNames[i];
        System.out.println(cls + " "+methodName);
        //codes used to access key values
        Collection coll = (Collection) methodNamesSet.get(methodName);
        System.out.println(cls + " "+methodNamesSet.get(methodName));
    }
```

i get a error `get` saying cannot resolve method get(java.lang.String)

is there any way to access the MultiValueMap

Comment: what does this returns `projectDetails.getClassDetailsMap().get(cls)`? and what is this `cls`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a compilation error with your code. There is no get method in Set.

> methodNamesSet.get(methodName)

To get method details, first loop through the set and then get method details from methodDetailsMap as below.

```
MultiValueMap<String, MethodDetails>  methodDetailsMap = projectDetails.getClassDetailsMap().get(0).getMethodDetailsMap();
       Set<String> methodNamesSet = methodDetailsMap.keySet();

        for(String str: methodNamesSet) {
                System.out.println(methodDetailsMap.get(str));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I read your code and as I understand first you need to get all method names of `cls` class then you want to get them one by one. So in the for loop you need to `get` from the `getMethodDetailsMap()`.This will help you:

```
for (int i = 0; i < methodNames.length; i++) {
            String methodName = methodNames[i];
            System.out.println(cls + " "+methodName);
            //codes used to access key values
            Collection coll = projectDetails.getClassDetailsMap().get(cls).getMethodDetailsMap().get(methodName);
            System.out.println(cls + " "+methodNamesSet.get(methodName));
        }
```